# How to pass quotes inside a string via remix?

Tags: solidity, remix

How do you pass in a value as a string via remix - if that value includes quotes?

For example

A function takes a string - in remix I enter:

```
<path id="svg_1" d="m-44.5,88.5c234,144 125,271 124.5,270.5c0.5,0.5 252.5,-74.5 253.5,-72.5c1,2 -12,141 -12.5,140.5c0.5,0.5 437.5,-39.5 437,-40c0.5,0.5 -9.5,-240.5 -10,-241c0.5,0.5 -219.5,320.5 -220,320" opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#6F5C2A"/>
```

Because this code that I'm trying to store as a string, has quotes in it, remix thinks there are multiple strings being passed, when the function only takes one string.

So how do I pass something like this into remix such that returning the string returns the code properly?

`\"m-44........\"` does not work unless its single quotes and then it returns the string improperly

Comment: Hi Zach, do you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you store the strings in the contract in encoded version? Everytime you are saving data in the smart contract you can encode the strings from the frontend by using `encodeURIComponent()` and everytime you need to read that particular data you can decode it by using `decodeURIComponent()`.

Comment: Ideally so that if some dapp or site calls the function they can return the properly formatted svg info and display it without needing to convert anything.